# Teamcity run build from one of vcs roots

Tags: version-control, teamcity

I have TeamCity configuration which contains 2 vcs roots with identical directory structure:

- root_1_svn
- root_2_git

Build Steps:

- ms_build_1
- ms_build_2

Is it possible to build a solution for the vcs root in which there were changes only?

Example:

- if updated root_1_svn, then TC run ms_build_1, ms_build_2 for code from root_1_svn only
- if updated root_2_git, then TC run ms_build_1, ms_build_2 for code from root_2_git only

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Instead of one build configuration with 2 vcs roots, create two build configurations with one vcs in each of them. This is how it should be done.

Comment: Both vcs roots have similar build steps, and I think it's the most easy way to support. If I update configuration in one place, logic appears for both vcs roots.

Comment: That's why we are using templates. Convert your build configuration into template, then create two builds based on it. Changes made in template will be reflected in both build configurations.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!